# DocumentRoot is password protected but no htaccess file?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, password, .htaccess

At some point I pw protected `/var/www/` for security purposes (my actual hosted websites are located in a different path), now I would like to host something publicly in `/var/www/` but do not know how to remove the pw protection. There is no `.htaccess` file present in the directory or the parent.

What other ways could the directory be protected? Some sort of apache config file?

Comment: Is there a /etc/apache2/.htpasswd  ?

Comment: by the way: I assumed "pw protected /var/www/' we are talking protection from a browser seeing the contents of a dir and not that you are not allowed putting files in /var/www/ yourself from command line?

Comment: If listing /var/www is forbidden (good idea), surely you could solve it by creating /var/www/foo and list that directory? The block is not recursive, is it?

Comment: @bigbadonk420 that's what I'm trying to do im afraid

Comment: Maybe directory listing is completely disabled in Apache? See http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/06/03/faq-how-to-disable-directory-browsing-in-apachehttpd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make some changes in your apache configuration file.

Open Terminal

```
 sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

```
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

Make changes in AllowOverride None As.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now your apache will not recognize .htaccess files in your system.